# Configure JMS with ActiveMQ in Thorntail

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly, thorntail

I have a little issue about configuring JMS on Thorntail. In my project for development purpose I'm using Wildfly, but for remote server, we are using (my team) IBM Portal. I upgraded the local server from Wildfly to Thorntail and after I want to launch my app locally (using maven), it crashed. I looked into logs and I found that it gives my:

```
2019-12-04 10:49:50,957 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "myproject.war")) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.jms.notification"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.\"myproject.notifications.service.impl.JmsNotificationServiceImpl\".connectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.jms.notification]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.\"myproject.notifications.service.impl.JmsNotificationServiceImpl\".topic is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.jms.notification]"
    ]
}
2019-12-04 10:49:50,994 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "myproject.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.jms.notification"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.\"myproject.notifications.service.impl.JmsNotificationServiceImpl\".connectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.jms.notification]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.\"myproject.notifications.service.impl.JmsNotificationServiceImpl\".topic is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.env.jms.notification]"
    ]
}
```

In our local environment we didn't configured any queue for JMS purposes, becouse our main queue mechanism was on remote server (IBM Portal). 
There is some code we are using:

```
public class JmsNotificationServiceImpl implements JmsNotificationService {

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/notificationCF")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/topic/notification")
    private Topic topic;

    @Override
    public void send(String string) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);

            log.info("Sending JMS message to topic...");
            producer.send(session.createObjectMessage(string));
            log.info("Message sent succesfull.");
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new Exception("Error while creation or sending jms message", e);
        }
    }

}
```

I found that there is a build in ActiveMQ in Thorntail, but I don't really know how to configure ConnectionFactory and Topic in ActiveMQ. Could anyone help me to understand where put some configuration and how to configure it?

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of `standalone.xml` configuration from WildFly? It should be pretty straightforward to translate that into Thorntail `project-defaults.yml`. Though to be honest, I think that staying with WildFly would be better for your purpose, as it's probably much closed to the target environment.

Comment: Could you tell me where can I found this standalone.xml file? I found on github on some random project, there is a project-defaults.yml, but how I can understand, it's for communication between Thorntail and ActiveMQ (eg. remote), but I want use build-in activeMQ. So do you know how to configure a ConnectionFactory and Topic in build-in activeMQ?

Comment: OK, so in your WildFly setup, you don't configure the built-in Artemis server and use the remote messaging server? But in your Thorntail setup, you want to use the built-in ActiveMQ Artemis messaging server? Here's a simple test case that shows the absolute basics: https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/javaee/messaging

Comment: To be clear I'm not using any special configuration to use Artemis. I saw that the  fraction auto-detect add me automatically massaging fraction, and this is.

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic project-defaults.yml That allows your thorntail instance to connect to an remote Message Broker

```
swarm:
  network:
    socket-binding-groups:
      standard-sockets:
        outbound-socket-bindings:
          remote-activemq-socket-binding:
            remote-host: 127.0.0.1
            remote-port: 61616
  messaging-activemq:
    servers:
      default:
        remote-connectors:
          remote-activemq-connector:
            socket-binding: remote-activemq-socket-binding
        pooled-connection-factories:
          remote-connection-factory:
            user: myuser
            password: otherpassword
            connectors:
              - remote-activemq-connector
            entries:
              - 'java:/jms/remote-mq'
              - 'java:/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory'
        jms-queues:
          session-tracking-queue:
            entries:
              entry: 'java:/jms/queue/testQueue'
```

Requires the following dependency to be included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```